# Detecting when a volume is mounted in Windows with Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, device, volume

I am trying to understand the documentation at MSDN regarding Device Events
and how to trigger a notification whenever a volume has been mounted.

I have managed to do this for USB devices using information presented in the following post: [detect usb drive/device using delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949782/detect-usb-drive-device-using-delphi)

as well as other information found on the internet,
but I have noticed that it would be easier to detect when a volume has been mounted directly.

So my question is: how do I implement Device Events handling in my Delphi app?

I am looking at the following documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363217(v=vs.85).aspx

But I can't really figure out how to get it up and running.

So far I have tried the following code, which compiles properly,
but nothing happens, please push me in the right direction:

```
PDevBroadcastHdr  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
  DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record
    dbch_size       : DWORD;
    dbch_devicetype : DWORD;
    dbch_reserved   : DWORD;
  end;

  PDevBroadcastHandle = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
  DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE = packed record
    dbch_size       : DWORD       ;
    dbch_devicetype : DWORD       ;
    dbch_reserved   : DWORD       ;
    dbch_handle     : THandle     ;
    dbch_hdevnotify : HDEVNOTIFY  ;
    dbch_eventguid  : TGUID       ;
    dbch_nameoffset : LongInt     ;
    dbch_data       : byte        ;
  end;

...


procedure WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage);

const
  DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE = $0006;
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT: TGUID = '{B5804878-1A96-11D2-8FFD-00A0C9A06D32}';

...

function TForm1.RegisterThis: Boolean;
var
  dbv: DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
  Size: Integer;
  r: Pointer;
begin
  Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE);
  ZeroMemory(@dbv, Size);
  dbv.dbch_size := Size;
  dbv.dbch_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE;
  dbv.dbch_reserved := 0;
  dbv.dbch_handle  := 0;
  dbv.dbch_hdevnotify := nil;
  dbv.dbch_eventguid := GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT;
  dbv.dbch_nameoffset := 0;
  dbv.dbch_data := 0;

  r := RegisterDeviceNotification(FWindowHandle, @dbv, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);


  if Assigned(r) then Result := True;
end;


procedure TForm1.WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  VData: PDevBroadcastHandle;
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello!');
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Found a component on a forum regarding this. It is called TSHChangeNotify and was written by Elliott Shevinm back in 2000 (!)

[See the forum thread here](http://bcbjournal.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1809). It contains the sourcecode and a fix.
Theres also an article written by Zarko Gajic which explains how it works
[found here](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa030403b.htm)

It works perfectly fine in Delphi XE7 on Windows 8.1 when using VCL only.

**UPDATE:** I modified the code so it now runs on Delphi XE7 with Firemonkey.
[The updated code can be found here.](http://bcbj.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1809&p=7859#p7859)

The way I set it up is by setting `TSHChangeNotify.HardDriveOnly` to **FALSE**
and putting `TSHChangeNotify.Execute` inside main forms `OnCreate` procedure.

---

Thanks to Dalija and David, I received some good information and code which came in handy.

However their answers did not solve my problem.

Like David said in one of the comments, he just wanted to "push me in the right direction" as I myself suggested in my question. Fair enough.

I started Googling for "guid_io_volume_mount c++" to see if I could find some usable code elsewhere that I could port.

I came across this forum post: http://www.mofeel.net/957-microsoft-public-vc-language/2343.aspx

The OP mentioned in his code that CreateFileA should be used in order to basically "monitor" whenever a mount point has changed.

A mount point seems to be the drive letter, for example C:, D:, E: etc...

So basically what happens is that by using the following code

```
var
  dbv: DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
  Size: Integer;
  r: Pointer;
begin

  Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE);
  ZeroMemory(@dbv, Size);
  dbv.dbch_size := Size;
  dbv.dbch_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE;
  dbv.dbch_reserved := 0;
  dbv.dbch_handle  := CreateFileA('\\.\C:', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ+FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL + FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);
  dbv.dbch_hdevnotify := 0;
  dbv.dbch_nameoffset := 0;

  r := RegisterDeviceNotification(fHandle, @dbv, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);

  if Assigned(r) then Result := True;
```

we let the OS know that whenever "C:" has changed its mount state (mount/dismount), the OS will send a message to our WndProc message catcher.

My full source is avaible below, still a bit buggy, but it presents a concept so far.

It can detect when a specified volume is mounted, at least.
Dismount is detected when you right click on a volume and select "Eject".

Now remember, this code can do more than just detecting when mount points are changed, [this MSDN article has all the GUID's you need to do some pretty neat stuff.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363217(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.dialogs;

type
  TDeviceDetector = class
  protected
    fHandle: THandle;
    fLogger: TMemo;

    fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK      ,
    fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK    ,
    fOnDEVICE_BECOMING_READY     ,
    fOnDEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST   ,
    fOnMEDIA_ARRIVAL             ,
    fOnMEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST       ,
    fOnMEDIA_REMOVAL             ,
    fOnVOLUME_CHANGE             ,
    fOnVOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE        ,
    fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT           ,
    fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED    ,
    fOnVOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE  ,
    fOnVOLUME_LOCK               ,
    fOnVOLUME_LOCK_FAILED        ,
    fOnVOLUME_MOUNT              ,
    fOnVOLUME_NAME_CHANGE        ,
    fOnVOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK        ,
    fOnVOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE ,
    fOnVOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT    ,
    fOnVOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE   ,
    fOnVOLUME_UNLOCK             ,
    fOnVOLUME_WEARING_OUT        : TNotifyEvent;

    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure Log(AStr: string);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function RegisterThis: Boolean;
    property Logger: TMemo read fLogger write fLogger;
  published
    property OnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK      : TNotifyEvent read fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK     write fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK     ;
    property OnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK    : TNotifyEvent read fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK   write fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK   ;
    property OnDEVICE_BECOMING_READY     : TNotifyEvent read fOnDEVICE_BECOMING_READY    write fOnDEVICE_BECOMING_READY    ;
    property OnDEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST   : TNotifyEvent read fOnDEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST  write fOnDEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST  ;
    property OnMEDIA_ARRIVAL             : TNotifyEvent read fOnMEDIA_ARRIVAL            write fOnMEDIA_ARRIVAL            ;
    property OnMEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST       : TNotifyEvent read fOnMEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST      write fOnMEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST      ;
    property OnMEDIA_REMOVAL             : TNotifyEvent read fOnMEDIA_REMOVAL            write fOnMEDIA_REMOVAL            ;
    property OnVOLUME_CHANGE             : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_CHANGE            write fOnVOLUME_CHANGE            ;
    property OnVOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE        : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE       write fOnVOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE       ;
    property OnVOLUME_DISMOUNT           : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT          write fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT          ;
    property OnVOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED    : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED   write fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED   ;
    property OnVOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE  : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE write fOnVOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE ;
    property OnVOLUME_LOCK               : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_LOCK              write fOnVOLUME_LOCK              ;
    property OnVOLUME_LOCK_FAILED        : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_LOCK_FAILED       write fOnVOLUME_LOCK_FAILED       ;
    property OnVOLUME_MOUNT              : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_MOUNT             write fOnVOLUME_MOUNT             ;
    property OnVOLUME_NAME_CHANGE        : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_NAME_CHANGE       write fOnVOLUME_NAME_CHANGE       ;
    property OnVOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK        : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK       write fOnVOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK       ;
    property OnVOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE write fOnVOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE;
    property OnVOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT    : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT   write fOnVOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT   ;
    property OnVOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE   : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE  write fOnVOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE  ;
    property OnVOLUME_UNLOCK             : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_UNLOCK            write fOnVOLUME_UNLOCK            ;
    property OnVOLUME_WEARING_OUT        : TNotifyEvent read fOnVOLUME_WEARING_OUT       write fOnVOLUME_WEARING_OUT       ;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  dd: TDeviceDetector;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  PDevBroadcastHdr  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
  DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record
    dbch_size       : DWORD;
    dbch_devicetype : DWORD;
    dbch_reserved   : DWORD;
  end;

  PDevBroadcastHandle = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
  DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE = record
    dbch_size       : DWORD;
    dbch_devicetype : DWORD;
    dbch_reserved   : DWORD;
    dbch_handle     : THandle;
    dbch_hdevnotify : HDEVNOTIFY;
    dbch_eventguid  : TGUID;
    dbch_nameoffset : LONG;
    dbch_data: array [0..0] of Byte;
  end;

const
  DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES = $00000004;

  DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = $8006;
  DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE = $0006;

  GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK      : TGUID = '{bc56c139-7a10-47ee-a294-4c6a38f0149a}';
  GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK    : TGUID = '{a3b6d27d-5e35-4885-81e5-ee18c00ed779}';
  GUID_IO_DEVICE_BECOMING_READY     : TGUID = '{d07433f0-a98e-11d2-917a-00a0c9068ff3}';
  GUID_IO_DEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST   : TGUID = '{d07433d0-a98e-11d2-917a-00a0c9068ff3}';
  GUID_IO_MEDIA_ARRIVAL             : TGUID = '{d07433c0-a98e-11d2-917a-00a0c9068ff3}';
  GUID_IO_MEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST       : TGUID = '{d07433d1-a98e-11d2-917a-00a0c9068ff3}';
  GUID_IO_MEDIA_REMOVAL             : TGUID = '{d07433c1-a98e-11d2-917a-00a0c9068ff3}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE             : TGUID = '{7373654a-812a-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE        : TGUID = '{3a1625be-ad03-49f1-8ef8-6bbac182d1fd}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT           : TGUID = '{d16a55e8-1059-11d2-8ffd-00a0c9a06d32}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED    : TGUID = '{E3C5B178-105D-11D2-8FFD-00A0C9A06D32}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE  : TGUID = '{062998b2-ee1f-4b6a-b857-e76cbbe9a6da}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK               : TGUID = '{50708874-c9af-11d1-8fef-00a0c9a06d32}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK_FAILED        : TGUID = '{ae2eed10-0ba8-11d2-8ffb-00a0c9a06d32}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT              : TGUID = '{b5804878-1a96-11d2-8ffd-00a0c9a06d32}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_NAME_CHANGE        : TGUID = '{2de97f83-4c06-11d2-a532-00609713055a}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK        : TGUID = '{799a0960-0a0b-4e03-ad88-2fa7c6ce748a}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE : TGUID = '{2de97f84-4c06-11d2-a532-00609713055a}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT    : TGUID = '{c79eb16e-0dac-4e7a-a86c-b25ceeaa88f6}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE   : TGUID = '{af39da42-6622-41f5-970b-139d092fa3d9}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNLOCK             : TGUID = '{9a8c3d68-d0cb-11d1-8fef-00a0c9a06d32}';
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_WEARING_OUT        : TGUID = '{873113ca-1486-4508-82ac-c3b2e5297aaa}';




function WDE_GUID_To_String(AGUID: TGUID): string; //WDE stands for Windows Device Events
begin
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK     then result := 'GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK'     else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK   then result := 'GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK'   else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_DEVICE_BECOMING_READY    then result := 'GUID_IO_DEVICE_BECOMING_READY'    else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_DEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST  then result := 'GUID_IO_DEVICE_BECOMING_READY'    else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_MEDIA_ARRIVAL            then result := 'GUID_IO_MEDIA_ARRIVAL'            else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_MEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST      then result := 'GUID_IO_MEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST'      else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_MEDIA_REMOVAL            then result := 'GUID_IO_MEDIA_REMOVAL'            else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE            then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE'            else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE       then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE'       else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT          then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT'          else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED   then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED'   else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE' else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK              then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK'              else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK_FAILED       then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK_FAILED'       else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT             then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT'             else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_NAME_CHANGE       then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_NAME_CHANGE'       else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK       then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK'       else

  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE' else

  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT   then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT'   else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE  then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE'  else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNLOCK            then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNLOCK'            else
  if AGUID = GUID_IO_VOLUME_WEARING_OUT       then result := 'GUID_IO_VOLUME_WEARING_OUT';
end;



constructor TDeviceDetector.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
end;

destructor TDeviceDetector.Destroy;
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(fHandle);
  inherited;
end;

function TDeviceDetector.RegisterThis: Boolean;
var
  dbv: DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
  Size: Integer;
  r: Pointer;
begin
  Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE);
  ZeroMemory(@dbv, Size);
  dbv.dbch_size := Size;
  dbv.dbch_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE;
  dbv.dbch_reserved := 0;
  dbv.dbch_handle  := CreateFileA('\\.\E:', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ + FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL + FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);
  dbv.dbch_hdevnotify := RegisterDeviceNotification(fHandle, @dbv, DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);;
  dbv.dbch_nameoffset := 0;


  if Assigned(dbv.dbch_hdevnotify) then Result := True;
end;

procedure TDeviceDetector.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  var data: PDevBroadcastHdr;
      data_H: PDevBroadcastHandle;
begin
  if Message.wParam = DBT_CUSTOMEVENT then  //according to MSDN, DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE structure is treated as a custom event.
  begin
    Data := PDevBroadcastHdr(Message.LParam); //we need to treat this custom evend a DEV_BROADCAST_HDR structure first...

    if Data^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE then //then we check if the device type is DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE
    begin
      data_H := PDevBroadcastHandle(Message.lParam); //if the device type is DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE, we treat the custom event as a DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE structure

      //final step is to see what GUID the event of the structure DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE has

      Log(WDE_GUID_To_String(data_H^.dbch_eventguid));

      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK)      = true then if assigned(fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK)      then fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK(self)      else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_CDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK)    = true then if assigned(fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK)    then fOnCDROM_EXCLUSIVE_UNLOCK(self)    else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_DEVICE_BECOMING_READY)     = true then if assigned(fOnDEVICE_BECOMING_READY)     then fOnDEVICE_BECOMING_READY(self)     else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_DEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST)   = true then if assigned(fOnDEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST)   then fOnDEVICE_EXTERNAL_REQUEST(self)   else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_MEDIA_ARRIVAL)             = true then if assigned(fOnMEDIA_ARRIVAL)             then fOnMEDIA_ARRIVAL(self)             else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_MEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST)       = true then if assigned(fOnMEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST)       then fOnMEDIA_EJECT_REQUEST(self)       else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_MEDIA_REMOVAL)             = true then if assigned(fOnMEDIA_REMOVAL)             then fOnMEDIA_REMOVAL(self)             else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE)             = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_CHANGE)             then fOnVOLUME_CHANGE(self)             else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE)        = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE)        then fOnVOLUME_CHANGE_SIZE(self)        else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT)           = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT)           then fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT(self)           else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED)    = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED)    then fOnVOLUME_DISMOUNT_FAILED(self)    else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE)  = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE)  then fOnVOLUME_FVE_STATUS_CHANGE(self)  else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK)               = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_LOCK)               then fOnVOLUME_LOCK(self)               else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_LOCK_FAILED)        = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_LOCK_FAILED)        then fOnVOLUME_LOCK_FAILED(self)        else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT)              = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_MOUNT)              then fOnVOLUME_MOUNT(self)              else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_NAME_CHANGE)        = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_NAME_CHANGE)        then fOnVOLUME_NAME_CHANGE(self)        else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK)        = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK)        then fOnVOLUME_NEED_CHKDSK(self)        else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE) = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE) then fOnVOLUME_PHYSICAL_CONFIGURATION_CHANGE(self) else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT)    = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT)    then fOnVOLUME_PREPARING_EJECT(self)    else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE)   = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE)   then fOnVOLUME_UNIQUE_ID_CHANGE(self)   else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_UNLOCK)             = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_UNLOCK)             then fOnVOLUME_UNLOCK(self)             else
      if IsEqualGUID(data_H^.dbch_eventguid, GUID_IO_VOLUME_WEARING_OUT)        = true then if assigned(fOnVOLUME_WEARING_OUT)        then fOnVOLUME_WEARING_OUT(self);
    end;

  end;
end;

procedure TDeviceDetector.Log(AStr: string);
begin
  fLogger.Lines.Add(AStr);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dd := TDeviceDetector.Create;
  dd.Logger := Memo1;
  if dd.RegisterThis = true then Memo1.Lines.Add('Registered!') else Memo1.Lines.Add('Failed to register!');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dd.free;
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of problems with what you have so far. Here is what I can see.

**Incorrect recipient**

You are passing a window handle to `RegisterDeviceNotification`. However, it's far from clear that your window handle implements a message handler for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. I recommend using `AllocateHWnd` to obtain a window handle, and handle `WM_DEVICECHANGE` in the window procedure that you supply to `AllocateHWnd`.

**Failure to call UnregisterDeviceNotification**

The documentation of `RegisterDeviceNotification` says:

> Device notification handles returned by RegisterDeviceNotification must be closed by calling the UnregisterDeviceNotification function when they are no longer needed.

You fail to do this. You have to hold on to the handle returned by `RegisterDeviceNotification` and pass it to `UnregisterDeviceNotification` when you no longer want to receive notifications.

**Erroneous packing of records**

You declared packed records. This is a mistake. For reasons unclear to me, it seems to be a prevailing mistake for Delphi developers to pack their records. Packing results in poor performance. Even worse, when performing interop with aligned records, packing simply results in an incorrect laying out of the record. These records are not packed.

Furthermore, I don't believe that your record should include a `dbch_data` member. That's only used for `DBT_CUSTOMEVENT` and I don't think that applies to you. I would declare the record like this:

```
type
  DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE = record
    dbch_size       : DWORD       ;
    dbch_devicetype : DWORD       ;
    dbch_reserved   : DWORD       ;
    dbch_handle     : THandle     ;
    dbch_hdevnotify : HDEVNOTIFY  ;
    dbch_eventguid  : TGUID       ;
    dbch_nameoffset : LONG        ;
  end;
```

**Weak error checking**

You do check the return value of the call to `RegisterDeviceNotification`. That's good. But if that call fails then you don't call `GetLastError` to find out why, as described in the documentation. I'd write the call like this:

```
var
  DevNotificationHandle: HDEVNOTIFY;
....
DevNotificationHandle := RegisterDeviceNotification(...);
Win32Check(DevNotificationHandle <> 0);
```

That way any errors will be translated into exceptions with textual error messages representing the Win32 error code.

**Likely incorrect value of `dbch_devicetype`**

I think you should be passing `DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` rather than `DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE`. If you switch to `DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` and address all the points I raised above, then you will receive notifications. For instance:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FWindow: HWND;
    FDevNotificationHandle: HDEVNOTIFY;
    procedure WndMethod(var Message: TMessage);
    function HandleDeviceChange(Event: DWORD; Data: Pointer): Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE = record
    dbch_size: DWORD;
    dbch_devicetype: DWORD;
    dbch_reserved: DWORD;
    dbch_handle: THandle;
    dbch_hdevnotify: HDEVNOTIFY;
    dbch_eventguid: TGUID;
    dbch_nameoffset: LONG;
  end;

const
  DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = $0005;
  GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT: TGUID = '{B5804878-1A96-11D2-8FFD-00A0C9A06D32}';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  dbh: DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
begin
  FWindow := AllocateHWnd(WndMethod);
  dbh := Default(DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE);
  dbh.dbch_size := SizeOf(dbh);
  dbh.dbch_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
  dbh.dbch_eventguid := GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT;
  FDevNotificationHandle := RegisterDeviceNotification(FWindow, @dbh,
    DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
  Win32Check(FDevNotificationHandle <> nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDevNotificationHandle <> nil then
    Win32Check(UnregisterDeviceNotification(FDevNotificationHandle));
  DeallocateHWnd(FWindow);
end;

procedure TForm1.WndMethod(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_DEVICECHANGE:
      Message.Result := ord(HandleDeviceChange(Message.WParam,
        Pointer(Message.LParam)));
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FWindow, Message.Msg, Message.WParam,
      Message.LParam);
  end;
end;

function TForm1.HandleDeviceChange(Event: DWORD; Data: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%4x', [Event]));
  Result := True;
end;

end.
```

Note that a default set of notifications is broadcast to top-level windows. So you may not even need to register because I believe that volume changes are part of the default set.

Comment: No problem with dbch_size with a crippled DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE passed to RegisterDeviceNotification?

Comment: @Sertac you mean with dbch_data removed?

Comment: Yes, you are putting the size of the struct to dbch_size, but your struct is smaller than regular.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried your suggested code, it only reacts when a usb device is connected, I already have such thing working, what I need is to detect when a Volume is mounted.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That works out just fine. The call to `RegisterDeviceNotification` succeeds.

Comment: @AidVllasaliu Actually, it's your code. I just fixed all the mistakes. I don't want to write the rest of your program for you. Perhaps you need to use a different `dbch_devicetype`. I don't know. I just concentrated on fixing all the interop problems. I've pushed you in the right direction, as you asked. Is that not enough?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan oh, thanks. yes yes that is enough, but I still have a hard time figuring out why nothing happens when a volume is mounted/dismounted. Mounted is more important right now.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. I'm not an expert on device notification. I wonder if you might get what you need by reading the JEDI code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found some code from a JEDI code clone on github (I think) where all those records and bits and pieces were mentioned, but I couldnt find any usable example code.

Comment: Success! I got it working. Is it possible to add my answer somehow?

Comment: You can add an answer. You may need to wait some time. What did you do?

Comment: @Aid I find this very frustrating.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan answer posted

Comment: You've not heeded much of my advice. I have no interest in attempting to help somebody who does not want to be helped.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what? what do you mean? ofcourse you've helped, your information is important, not only to me, but to anybody who sees this post. Just because I didnt use your code doesn't mean it's not helpful. After all, I just needed a push in the right direction, you didn't want to bother to solve the problem, you just wanted to supply some knowledge, so I don't know what the problem seems to be.

Comment: In your answer you repeat mistakes that I point out in my answer.  I find that frustrating.  I've don't know what you mean about "bothering to solve the problem".  Stack Overflow isn't a site where people solve your problems.  It's a site where people attempt to answer the questions that are asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean the "packed record" mistake?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan regarding the DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE  "mistake". I don't think it's a mistake, MSDN suggest using DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE, and it works.

Comment: `DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE` is a mistake with the code in the question. As for your mistakes, I honestly don't want to get into this. I've gone to great lengths to point out a number of mistakes. I don't want to spend more time repeating myself. It's all in my answer. I'm very unimpressed by the way this question progressed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, the code in the question, but now we have an answer which corrects those mistakes. I don't see why you're clinging on to the question so much. It was a question, it has many errors probably. Together we solved the problem, so what's the deal? I'll leave it at this, if anybody wants to try my answer out and further develop it, go ahead. I wanted to detect when a volume is mounted, I succeeded. The rest is up to each and everyone to further develop the code.

Comment: No. Now we have an answer which repeats many of the mistakes. I've made my point. We can leave it at that.

Comment: Anybody is free to modify the code. I'll develop it further when needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your `WMDeviceChange` method like this to receive message:

```
procedure WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_DEVICECHANGE;
```

Also, since your `WMDeviceChange` method is part of the Form you should use Form window `Handle` to register message.

```
r := RegisterDeviceNotification(Handle, @dbv, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
```

Since `Handle` can be recreated during Form's lifetime you should override Form's `CreateWnd` method and add registration there.

Or even better, you can encapsulate functionality in another class:

```
  TDeviceDetector = class
  protected
    fHandle: THandle;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function RegisterThis: Boolean;
  end;

constructor TDeviceDetector.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
end;

destructor TDeviceDetector.Destroy;
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(fHandle);
  inherited;
end;

function TDeviceDetector.RegisterThis: Boolean;
var
  dbv: DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;
  Size: Integer;
  r: Pointer;
begin
  Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE);
  ZeroMemory(@dbv, Size);
  dbv.dbch_size := Size;
  dbv.dbch_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE;
  dbv.dbch_reserved := 0;
  dbv.dbch_handle  := 0;
  dbv.dbch_hdevnotify := nil;
  dbv.dbch_eventguid := GUID_IO_VOLUME_MOUNT;
  dbv.dbch_nameoffset := 0;
  dbv.dbch_data := 0;

  r := RegisterDeviceNotification(fHandle, @dbv, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);

  if Assigned(r) then Result := True;
end;

procedure TDeviceDetector.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Hello!');
    end
  else Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FHandle, Message.Msg, Message.wParam, Message.lParam); // Default Message Handler
end;
```

Comment: Top level windows get the messages anyway. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215(v=vs.85).aspx You aren't checking for errors. Try doing so. I'm sure you and I have talked about packed records before.

Comment: @David Yep, it looks like that top level windows do receive notifications even without registration.

Comment: @David Yes, we have talked about packed records before. Using packed in above code is fine, as well as not using packed. I don't use packed when I am not interacting with OS or other outside code, and when I don't stream the record. In other cases I do use packed because I either must use it to achieve same memory layout, or it is irrelevant but in that case packed serves as reminder that memory layout of record in question must be preserved.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You've got that wrong. This record is aligned. For the life of me I cannot understand why Delphi developers find this so hard to understand.

Comment: @David Yes, it is aligned and using packed on it makes no difference, what I am trying to tell you is that sometimes using packed makes difference in sense that you must use it. I prefer not to dwell on whether record is aligned or not, and whether I must use packed or not when I am interacting with other systems, so I use packed. Call me lazy if you will...

Comment: No! Using packed results in a record that is **not** aligned.  I'm not calling you lazy.  I'm calling you wrong.  It is clearly critical to lay out the record correctly on both sides.  Using packed on one side and aligned on the other leads to different layouts.  As a broad rule, Win32 structs are aligned.  I'm beginning to think that you don't understand what I mean by aligned.

Comment: @David When record is defined `tr = record a, b, c: DWORD; end;` compiler will generate exactly the same code for accessing it's fields even if you add `packed` to it. I think I know what you mean when you say aligned... but...

Comment: In that case the layout will be the same because all members have the same size.  The record in the question has a pointer in it. That's 8 bytes wide sometimes.  Alignment also means that the overall structure has an alignment property matching the largest alignment of any of its members.  Which is a big performance issue.  It becomes a correctness issue on certain architectures which enforce alignment of data access.  The fact that you think that alignment and packing don't matter when interacting with other systems tells me that you do not understand this at all.

Comment: I understand perfectly well.  You appear to be saying that you can lay a record out one way one one side of the interop boundary, and lay it out a different way on the other side of the boundary, and that both sides will read and write from the same fields.

Comment: @David No, that is not what I am saying.

Comment: That's exactly what you are saying. Because you are saying that it is fine to pack on one side and align on the other.

Comment: Or perhaps the problem is that you think that the Windows header files declare packed structures. If you thought that it would explain why you believe that packing on the Delphi side is correct. But if you believe that you are wrong.

Comment: @David Nope, you are completely on the wrong track... that's why just never mind, I will not be able to get the message through...

Comment: I guess I'll have to give up then and leave you in the belief that Win32 records are packed.

Comment: @David I know they are not packed.... that is why I know that you completely don't get what I am saying and I must look like an idiot to you...  just forget it...

Comment: If you know that they are not packed, why do you pack them? I don't see the sense in choosing to do something that you know to be wrong. For the life of my I cannot understand this obsession with packing records.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I tried your code, just like I tried Davids code, still only getting USB device notifications.

Comment: Success! I got it working. Is it possible to add my answer somehow?

Comment: @AidVllasaliu You have "Answer Your Own Question" button at the bottom of this page. Use this, but provide full answer to the question with all relevant code and information.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar answer posted!