# Delphi: How do I make VCL controls thread-safe when interacting with data from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, vcl

In a unit `DeviceManager`, I have the VCL form `formDeviceManager` that interacts with data from another `TThread`, `DetectDrivesThread`. `DetectDrivesThread` is created and executed in the main form of the program.

```
procedure TDetectDrivesThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    sleep(1000);
    try
      DetectDrives.refreshRemovableDrivesList(formMain.dbConn);
    finally
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This is the constructor for TDetectDrivesThread:

```
constructor TDetectDrivesThread.Create();
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  DetectDrives := TDetectDrives.Create(formMain.dbConn);
  FreeOnTerminate := false;
end;
```

`formDeviceManager` has several controls that allows the user to view, remove and change data about such drives. However, my controls are not thread-safe and while `DetectDrivesThread` is executing , I could use the "Remove Device" button in `formDeviceManager` to Free the object corresponding to the USB Device. This can cause the program to crash if any methods from that object are running.

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question, I don't have much knowledge of multi-threading and this is my first proper coding project.

Comment: Your approach is doomed to fail. I suggest you read this [excellent primer](http://www.martincharvey.net/mch_custom_pages/Original/ToC.html) to better understand threading in general.

Comment: Anyway using a thread to detect (USB?) drives is not the correct way of doing things, you can get [notified when a disk is being inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7984788/800214)

Comment: If making VCL controls thread-safe were that easy, I guess Embarcadero had long done this by themselves.

Comment: So true: https://twitter.com/danny_thorpe/status/22929832870

Comment: Weird. You've basically coded a timer. But yeah, polling ain't the answer here.

Comment: You should decouple the user interface (UI, the forms) and the processing (Probably your DeviceManager). Put the UI in one unit and the processing in another unit. Your DeviceManager should be a class which encapsulate a TThread to execute lengthy process in a worker thread. You can then use standard protect data using critical section and similar objects to make the class thread safe.

Comment: @fpiette how am I able to pull all of the UI in one unit? My program is a USB backup software. The main form is a tray icon, I've got a form for the Device Manager and a form for the Setup Wizard (which lets the user configure the backup settings for any newly plugged in device). For the units, I have "USBDevices" which holds the class "TUSBDevice" and all the relevant methods and I have unit "DetectDrives" that's in charge of detecting newly plugged in devices, creating a new Setup Wizard form when a new one is found and also going through each USB device and calling their CopyNewFiles() meth

Comment: @Radu M. You can use several units for your user interface, no problem. But use only one class to encapsulate all the processing completely independant of the user interface. When designing this class, think you have a console mode application which must do the same processing. The important point is to completely decouple processing and user interface. Create a blackbox for processing (That is a class, or more) which has methods, properties and events. Make it thread safe which is easy if it doesn't use the user interface (VCL).